Solve for $x$ in $6^x + 2^x = 5^x + 3^x$.
Solve for $x$ in $6^x + 2^x = 5^x + 3^x$.
This is a problem in my calculus text (in the section for Basic theorems of differentiable functions and Applications of differential calculus). I've been working on it for 2 hours but couldn't seem to crack it. Clearly $x= 0$ and $x=1$ are roots. Looking at the graph, it seems we need to show that these are the only roots. My original plan was to let $f(x) = 6^x + 2^x - 5^x - 3^x$. Suppose there is a third root for $f(x) = 0$; then $f'(x) = 0$ must have at least two roots, and thus $f''(x) = 0$ must have at least one root. I'd try to show that $f''(x)=0$ has no roots, but looking at the graph, it occurred to me that $f''(x) =0$ indeed has roots. I then considered showing that $f(x) > 0$ for $x \in (\infty, 0)$, $f(x) < 0$ for $x \in (0, 1)$, and $f(x) >0$ for $x \in (1, \infty),$ but I struggled to prove the latter two cases. I hope to receive some help.
Thank you!

Check here and also here.

@BoweiTang thank you so much! The solution using MVT is brilliant!
